# Plotting measured data along with Bode plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I am taking a circuits class and for lab we need to do a little work with MATLAB to plot some of the results.  I got the following code which I used to generate a Bode plot of the transfer function for a filter we were designing.  I sort of get how it works but I don't really know or use MATLAB outside of this class.

```
clc;
close all
s=tf('s');
w=628*1000;
H=(1/(1 + 1.85*s/w + s^2/w^2))*(1/(1 + 0.77*s/w + s^2/w^2));
figure;
bode(H)
```

This worked fine but now I need to plot the transfer function I measured in the lab against this data on the SAME plot axis.  How can I plot both of them together.  I have the lab data as a list of gain frequency pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `bode(H)`, try:

```
[mag,ph,w] = bode(H); % gets the data without generating the figure
plot(w, mag, 'b'); % plots only the magnitudes

freqs = data(:,1); % These 2 lines depend on how your data is formatted
gains = data(:,2); % These 2 lines depend on how your data is formatted

hold on % will add new content to the existing figure without erasing the previous content
plot(freqs, gains, 'r');
hold off
```

you could also try (inspired by http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/bodeplot.html) :

```
h = bodeplot(H);
setoptions(h,'FreqUnits','Hz','PhaseVisible','off'); % suppress the phase plot


freqs = data(:,1); % These 2 lines depend on how your data is formatted
gains = data(:,2); % These 2 lines depend on how your data is formatted

hold on % will add new content to the existing figure without erasing the previous content
plot(freqs, gains, 'r');
hold off
```

Comment: That works but it adds my plot to the phase diagram instead of the magnitude diagram.  How can I fix this.  (I don't even care about the phase plot if I can just get rid of it.)

Comment: I actually figured out that last issue on my own by plotting the data before doing the bode.  Kind of a hack but all I needed.  Thanks for solving my main problem though.